# ssh-keygen: command not found in Docker

Tags: docker, ssh

I am trying to run this below command inside a docker container
(`centos 7` as the base image)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N ""
```

and I get this error:

> ssh-keygen: command not found

And this is the `Dockerfile` I used to build the container

```
FROM centos:7

ENV VER "0.12.9"

RUN yum update -y && yum install wget -y && yum install unzip -y
RUN yum install epel-release -y && yum install ansible -y

RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${VER}/terraform_${VER}_linux_amd64.zip
RUN unzip terraform_${VER}_linux_amd64.zip
RUN mv terraform /usr/local/bin/  
RUN rm -rf terraform_${VER}_linux_amd64.zip
```

Can someone help me, Please?

Comment: You need to install `ssh`.

Comment: can you tell me how can I do this? Are you sure? I hough ssh-keygen comes in built to centos? Can you help?

Comment: You run `um` there to install four other commands, just do the for `ssh` (and check what CentOS calls the package, I run a different distro).  Also, you can install multiple packages at one so you only need one `yum install a b c d e f` for a ... f.

Comment: additional For ubuntu you can  do

```apt install openssh-server  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ssh-keygen` is command provided by OpenSSH, you need to install it.

Add `yum install openssh-clients -y` to your Dockerfile.

```
FROM centos:7

ENV VER "0.12.9"

RUN yum update -y && yum install wget -y && yum install unzip -y
RUN yum install epel-release -y && yum install ansible -y && yum install openssh-clients -y

RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${VER}/terraform_${VER}_linux_amd64.zip
RUN unzip terraform_${VER}_linux_amd64.zip
RUN mv terraform /usr/local/bin/  
RUN rm -rf terraform_${VER}_linux_amd64.zip
```

Comment: Should I need to start the `sshd` service and enable it as well?

Comment: No, you don't need the daemon to generate a key, `openssh-clients` only installs the client not the server anyway.

Comment: At least on Debian: `openssh-client` not `openssh-clients`